# intellisense not working in vs2012

Tags: visual-studio, user-controls, visual-studio-2012, telerik, intellisense

I have a solution with 50 projects. It was written in VS2010 and later converted to VS2012. All intelisense work great, **except for markup intelisense (Aspx, ascx..) for "telerik" tag and custom created controls. asp tag works fine**

If I create a new project and reference telerik, then intelisense works, so I guess there's something wrong with my project. I tried to compare web.configs side by side. They look identical. Assemblies look identical as well.    My web.config looks like this:

```
<controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
        <add tagPrefix="custom" src="src/to/control" tagName="myControl1" />
        <add tagPrefix="custom" src="path...." tagName="myControl2" />
      </controls>
```

Things I've tried:
1. Tools->Options->Text Editor->C# (or All Languages)->General enable Auto List Members and Parameter Information in right hand side pane.
2.Tools->Import and Export settings->Reset all settings.
3.delete data from Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ReflectedSchemas
4. Delete cache in ProgramFiles\VisualStudio...
5. Reinstall visual studio
6. Run as administrator

If you have any clues or possible solutions, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Register your Telerik.Web.UI.dll in Gac and this solution work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen in Visual Studio 2013. Here's what I did to get Intellisense back:

1. Add a reference in your project to Telerik.Web.Design.dll.
2. Save your project.
3. Reload your project in the IDE. (I restarted VS, just in case.)

HTH!